# Showing two roads lane of one road

Tags: openstreetmap, geopandas, networkx, osmnx

I am using osmnx package to visualize a street network. I would like to visualize both (two) lanes in opposite directions of a road. I am using this code https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/162

How do I add the output point on the map?

```
import osmnx as ox

place_name = 'Cergy, France'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type = 'drive')
lines = []
for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    if 'geometry' in data:
        # if it has a geometry attribute (a list of line segments), add them
        # to the list of lines to plot
        xs, ys = data['geometry'].xy
        points = list(zip(xs, ys))
        #parallel shift distance
        h = 1

        if not data['oneway']:
            # for each point excluding the start point and end point, shift point based on 
            # line to next point
            transformed_points = [points[0]]
            # get pairs of points on the line segment
            for p1,p2 in zip(points[1:], points[2:]):
                (x1,y1) = parallel_point_shift(p1,p2,h)[0]
                transformed_points.append((x1,y1))

                transformed_points.append(points[-1])
                points = transformed_points

            lines.append(list(points))
    else:
    # if it doesn't have a geometry attribute, the edge is a straight
    # line from node to node
        x1 = G.nodes[u]['x']
        y1 = G.nodes[u]['y']
        x2 = G.nodes[v]['x']
        y2 = G.nodes[v]['y']

    if not data['oneway']:
        ((x1,y1), (x2,y2)) = parallel_point_shift((x1,y1),(x2,y2), h)

    line = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
    lines.append(line)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'parallel_point_shift' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function suffers some tiny bugs, let's fix them one by one and explore the code.

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import folium 
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, LineString, Point

# Adapted function from your link
def parallel_point_shift(p1, p2,  h):
    (x1,y1) = p1
    (x2,y2) = p2
    try:
        if y1 < y2:
            theta = np.arctan((x1-x2)/(y1-y2))
            x1 -= h*np.cos(theta)
            y1 += h*np.sin(theta)
            x2 -= h*np.cos(theta)
            y2 += h*np.sin(theta)
        elif y2 < y1:
            theta = np.arctan((x1-x2)/(y1-y2))
            x1 += h*np.cos(theta)
            y1 -= h*np.sin(theta)
            x2 += h*np.cos(theta)
            y2 -= h*np.sin(theta)
    except:
        raise ValueError("Error; unlucky division by 0.") # if y2 == y1
    
    p1 = (x1, y1)
    p2 = (x2, y2)

    return (p1, p2)
```

Then, download the data:

```
place_name = 'Cergy, France'
G_ori = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type = 'drive')
# reproject your input graph to a local cartographic reference frame
# to work in a cartesian space otherwise you will experience funny results...
G = ox.project_graph(G_ori, to_crs='EPSG:3812') # Lambert 08 seems a good choice here
```

Please, notice the most important part here, you have to project your data to a planar Cartesian surface, you **cannot** compute arctan with input values in degrees as you were doing, so, [Lambert 08](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_conique_conforme_de_Lambert#Lambert_2008) seems a good choice for your region.

```
lines = []
h = 1 # you can get this constant out of the loops
for u, v, data in G.edges(keys=False, data=True):
    if 'geometry' in data:
        # if it has a geometry attribute (a list of line segments), add them
        # to the list of lines to plot
        xs, ys = data['geometry'].xy
        points = list(zip(xs, ys))

        if not data['oneway']:
            # for each point excluding the start point and end point,
            # shift point based on line to next point
            transformed_points = [points[0]]
            # get pairs of points on the line segment
            for p1, p2 in zip(points[1:], points[2:]):
                ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) = parallel_point_shift(p1, p2, h)
                transformed_points.append((x1, y1))
            
            # Get this out of the for loop otherwise you will append
            # the last point during each iteration, which will lead to massive
            # amount of lines going nowhere...
            transformed_points.append(points[-1]) 
            lines.append(list(transformed_points))

    elif 'geometry' not in data:
    # if it doesn't have a geometry attribute, the edge is a straight
    # line from node to node
        p1 = G.nodes[u]['x'], G.nodes[u]['y']
        p2 = G.nodes[v]['x'], G.nodes[v]['y']

        if not data['oneway']: # indent one more level here
            ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) = parallel_point_shift(p1, p2, h)

    line = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
    lines.append(line)
```

After what, you can project back your data to [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) (better for plotting):

```
# this first line expand your line to a GeoDataFrame!
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [LineString(l) for l in lines] })
gdf.set_geometry('geometry', inplace=True) # set the geometry
gdf.set_crs('EPSG:3812', inplace=True) # set the actual CRS
gdf.to_crs('EPSG:4326', inplace=True) # reproject to WGS84
```

Finally, why not plotting a nice map, e.g. using [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/)?

```
m = folium.Map([49.0333, 2.0667],  tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=18, max_zoom=22)
# Do not forget to use your WGS84 input graph here!
# Input original data are shown in blue
ox.plot_graph_folium(G_ori, graph_map=m, edge_color='blue', edge_width=1)
folium.Choropleth(
    gdf,
    line_weight=1,
    line_color='green' # doubled roads are shown in green
).add_to(m)

m
```

[image: Results]

Zoom in a little:

[image: Zoomed-in results]

Please, notice that there still are some little glitches, especially at the joints; and as we exploded the graph into individual lines, the network is no more topologically correct. But, he, you can't have your cake and eat it right? ;)

Comment: Lots of thanks @s.k. I have tested. It seems  to be working nicely.

Comment: Is there possible to shift also both extremities of a line (origin-destination)? I have a new street network and all linestring are straight lines (a segment).